# Appium mobile automation view not recognizing activity

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, automation, appium

Appium mobile automation view not recognizing new activity on entering new activity after button click in android app throws Http 404 error, How can i make it recognises the view?

Comment: Hi Gowtham, please add context (code, examples, etc) and be more specific to help other user answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah thanks moretti-fabio throwing Nosuchelementerror after login in second activity caps.setCapability("appActivity", 'com.example.login'); caps.setCapability("appActivity", 'com.example.secondactivity'); driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.ImageView[@resource-id='com.logicvalley.emilie:id/keyboard']").click();

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please give a detailed explanation of your question so that others can understand it and answer it. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)